# CoordinatorLayout and hiding the toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using a single activity - multiple fragments structure.On the activity i'm using v7 toolbar as action bar . I have sever fragments with viewpagers , some with tabs as well.In one of my fragments i have recyclerview . My goal is when i'm scrolling i wanna collapse the bar and hide the floating action button.My floating button is on inside a `CoordinatorLayout` so it can be displayed properly.But this is inside the layout of the fragment(which is part of a viewpager) , and the `activity_main.xml` has root element another `CoordinatorLayout`. Does the fragment CL intercepts the work of the CL inside the layout of the activity,because when i scroll the recycler nothing happens.

Should i use new toolbar for every fragment or i can use one in the
activity and implement different behavior for into fragments?
Can anyone references any examples of using CoordinatorLayout and
collapsing the bar within nested fragments?

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work of the main `CoordinatorLayout` wasn't intercepted.Adding         `app:layout_behavior`  to the frame layout which is fragment container did the job.
Looks like this now:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```